# Convert UseRef to React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to convert my component to react hooks.

```
class AppMenu extends Component<Props> {
    menuRef = null;

    initMenu() {
        if (this.props.mode === 'horizontal') {
            const menuRef = new MetisMenu('#menu-bar').on('shown.metisMenu', event => {
                const menuClick = e => {
                    if (!event.target.contains(e.target)) {
                        menuRef.hide(event.detail.shownElement);
                    }
                };
                window.addEventListener('click', menuClick);
            });
            this.menuRef = menuRef;
        } else {
            this.menuRef = new MetisMenu('#menu-bar');
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert this to hooks? Especially the menuRef part.

I did `const menuRef = useRef(null);`, but how do I convert the `this.menuRef = new MetisMenu('#menu-bar');` to useRef? I tried `menuRef.current = new MetisMenu('#menu-bar');` but it throws an error.

Am I doing this the incorrect way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to implement my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
function AppMenu(props: Props) {
  const menuRef = useRef(null);

  function initMenu() {
    if (props.mode === "horizontal") {
      menuRef.current = new MetisMenu("#menu-bar").on(
        "shown.metisMenu",
        (event) => {
          const menuClick = (e) => {
            if (!event.target.contains(e.target)) {
              menuRef.hide(event.detail.shownElement);
            }
          };
          window.addEventListener("click", menuClick);
        }
      );
    } else {
      menuRef.current = new MetisMenu("#menu-bar");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initMenu();
  }, []);
}
```